# Create a table with mako

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

How do I create a table with alternating row highlighting using Mako?  What is the mako syntax, and what do I put into the css file?

I followed the pyramid tutorial to build my own app, but I am stuck creating a good browser based user interface.

Comment: have you write any code? Which type of output you have which you want to convert to html table?

Comment: I am importing a list of objects (which are SQLAlchemy queries), whose attributes I am displaying in the table.  The outputs are all strings and integers.  All my code is in python

Comment: Honestly for creating "good user interfaces" I've started looking to things like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) to plug in CSS.  Then there are prebuilt CSS classes you can assign your tables to and things like alternating row colors just work.  They do amazing things for easily making basic HTML and forms look nice and uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have data in list

```
<table>
            <tr>
                      <th>Column1</th>
                      <th>Column2</th>
                      <th>Column3</th>

            </tr>
            % for line in table_lines:
                      % if <check condition>:
                          <tr background="black">
                      % else:
                          <tr background="white">
                      % endif

                      <td>${line.column1}</p>
                      <td>${line.column2}</td>
                      <td>${line.column3}</td>
                      </tr>
            % endfor
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a rather convoluted syntax to do this.  But how do I make the table neat?  Such that each alternating row has a different background colour and there is a bit of spacing between the columns?

Comment: [CSS styling for tables](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) would be useful here, too.

Comment: I could not get the colours to alternate colours using the above code.  Instead, in my CSS file, I added:

`table 
tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#dfdfff; }
table 
tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#fafaff; }`

A very useful tool for creating css tables is the css table generator:

http://www.csstablegenerator.com/